# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'no_of' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

```
no_of = 0

def f1():
    global no_of
    no_of = 1
f1()
def f2():
    no_of = no_of + 1
    print no_of
f2()
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "test.py", line 10, in 
>           f2()
>         File "test.py", line 8, in f2
>           no_of = no_of + 1
>       UnboundLocalError: local variable 'no_of' referenced before assignment

Fine version

```
    no_of = 0

    def f1():
        global no_of
        no_of = 1
    f1()
    def f2():
    #    no_of = no_of + 1
        print no_of
    f2()
```

python test.py
1

Can you please assist me on difference on why first script gives UnboundLocalError while second one runs properly?

Comment: Could you clarify what is your first script, and what your second?

Comment: first and second script has only difference i.e :   no_of = no_of + 1in function f2.

Comment: You 're getting an error because you try to modify a global variable without using `global`